# I want to save a image file to server folder and save its path to mysql

Tags: mysql

The problem is that the image is not moved to UPLOAD_DIR path, but the path of that file is successfully inserted in server.

```
 <?php
$con=require_once("connection.php");

define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'http://hpms.hostei.com/images/');

$image= $_REQUEST['image'];             //byte image data received
$image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$data = base64_decode($image);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);// 

print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';


$code=0;
if($r=mysql_query("insert into images values('','$file')"))
{
$code=1;
}


print(json_encode($code));

mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi awais khan sar,

```
You can use the $_FILES server variable. $_REQUEST is used for GET and POST both method 

but you are uploading images i have also this problem and solved with this type. you can 

create post method from any mobile device then save it into folder using 

move_uploaded_file() if any query then tell me, Thanks Hiren kubavat.
```

Comment: dear hiren kubavat by $_request i'm receiving the byte image data from android.